# Add labels to polygons in google maps?

Tags: google-maps

How do I put a text label on a polygon in Google Maps?  Documentation deals with markers and icons, but I don't want a marker - this is not a point. ELabels was good but was made with V2 and breaks with V3.

Answer (score 1):

Create an custom [Overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#OverlayView) , you may place there any html-markup (e.g. an element that contains some text)